# Update Existing Records with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008

This question seems kind of silly but I ask because my SQL have become quite rusty.

I am trying to do a simple Update in a Microsoft SQL Database. I have an object representation of a Database table entry that I created myself.

It got all the fields that the Database table has and now all I need to do is update the original record in the database with the new data I got from a client application. I get every field from the client, even fields that weren't changed. I need to somehow make an SQL statement that:

1. Finds an existing record in the Database.
2. Updates the record only where the fields differ in data.

I am not even sure if it's possible to check for that in an SQL statement or if I simply have to just overwrite data regardless of it being the same as the original or not.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you use an ORM like nHibernate or Entity Framework, as they'll solve these issues for you.

Comment: @Dai Because I had 6 weeks to make a fairly heavy data application on my own as well as write a report to boot while documenting everything. So I wasn't thinking it through. It's a prototype so I could always switch to Entity or nHibernate later ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a methodology:

```
1.) Do a equi join
Table1
FirstName LastName PrimaryKey
Jay       Donner    1
Steven    Woods     2
Bruce     Beard     3
Table2 
Firstname LastName PrimaryKey
Jay       Donner    1
Steven    Wood      2
Bruce     Bears     3
```

So Inner join

```
Select A.FirstName,A.LastName,A.PrimaryKey
From Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B
On A.FirstName = B.FirstName 
AND A.LastName = B.LastName
```

Now the result set will be the fields that match
Jay Donner 1

Since you want to find the fields that do not match
you can use a subquery using the 'not in' command, as shown below:

```
Select  A.FirstName,A.LastName,A.PrimaryKey
From Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B 
ON A.PrimaryKey =B.PrimaryKey
Where A.PrimaryKey NOT IN (
    Select A.PrimaryKey
    From Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B
    On A.FirstName = B.FirstName 
    AND A.LastName = B.LastName
)
```

So the above query states: Find things that the primary key matches and for which the properties do not match values in the firstname and lastname fields.

```
Steven    Woods     2
Bruce     Bear      3
```

Now you know the primary keys of the things you need to update.  Next, iterate through your table with a update statement. Cursor is a piece of cake but I guess someone with tell you here to use recursion with CTE. Good luck with that...this is why I hate SQL. 
Here is an example of recursion using a cursor... So personally I would use c# with Entity Framework do this task and wrap it inside of as SSIS package with Executable command that I can put as a job in my SQL Server. 
Anyways!.. below is the iteration.

## Here the example code with no comments.

Declare @FName as nvarchar(50)

```
Declare @LName as nvarchar(100)
```

Declare  @PrimaryKeyas int

```
Declare PersonCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR


Select  A.FirstName,A.LastName,A.PrimaryKey
From Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B 
ON A.PrimaryKey =B.PrimaryKey
Where A.PrimaryKey NOT IN (
    Select A.PrimaryKey
    From Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B
    On A.FirstName = B.FirstName 
    AND A.LastName = B.LastName
)


OPEN PersonCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM PersonCursor

INTO @FName, @LName, @Email


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

-- do row specific stuff here



  UPDATE table2
   SET [EmployeeIdentification]=  @Fname, LastName=@LastName
   WHERE PrimaryKey=@PrimaryKey


FETCH NEXT FROM PersonCursor

INTO @FName, @LName, @Email

END


CLOSE PersonCursor

DEALLOCATE PersonCursor
```

Comment: Sorry if the answer is not complete but it should give you very very good idea.Let me know if I left out  a major loophole.

Comment: You are correct this does give me a very good idea. Pretty good answer which I'll go ahead and accept :)

Comment: If you have sql server 2008 or above using the merge command instead of my cursor would be great as recommended below. I forgot about that one.

Comment: Using a cursor to perform a simple update is a poor solution to the original problem

Comment: lol what did I tell you. I knew someone would complain about cursors. Is true. Just do a merge like I mentioned before.I was answering the question on the fly just to help. I will take the time later after work to answer with a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you're using ADO.NET...

When you load your object you'll be populating the primary key equivalent field on the object. Assuming it's an int identity or what-not, it'll be 0 if you're creating a new object. Otherwise, it'll be the value of what you got when you loaded it in from the database.

Of course, you'll have to ensure that value is there with whatever binding you're doing.

So when you're persisting the object to the database, check the primary key value on the object and call either an insert or an update method accordingly.

As Dai said however, your mileage will be intensely better if you select an ORM. Entity Framework has a bit of a learning curve. While I'm not a fan of PetaPoco it's pretty good for (very) small-scale projects.

Answer (score 0):

`Finds an existing record in the Database`

I would put it in a stored procedure.

`or if I simply have to just overwrite data regardless of it being the same as the original or not.`

I personally have used your approach where it updates all every time. Just make sure you are not updating only those columns that are not part of the primary key.  Example: `UPDATE table set firstname = @firstname, @lastname = lastname where userid = @userid`. just make sure you dont update `UserID`.

It wasnt clear based on your question, did you need to see actual code?

Comment: If possible sure. I wouldn't beg for code though, that's rude ^^. The issue is that I have a ton of fields. 24 to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but it gets very long winded very quickly and if there a nullable fields involved it gets horrendous. The standard approach, for a long time, has been just to overwrite all the fields.
If you want to avoid stomping over other peoples edits, I suggest you use a Timestamp field and just check that single column value hasn't changed when you do the update.

Comment: Thats assuming that in his particular use case multiple users will be updating the same record simultaneously or else you wouldnt even have to use TimeStamp, right?

Comment: The updates will be managed by a server so that they come in, in sequence. It's impossible for two clients to connect to the database at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Well dont have enough time to write query, but for a quick help the merge command can do the things you want.

follow the following links

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cannata/dbms/SQL%20Merge.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

Comment: Yeah that's right! Maybe I should edit my answer. I will now lol!